# Error en context del fragment en un RecyclerView Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-context

Soy nuevo en Android, recién vi un video en youtube sobre un RecyclerView mostrando datos almacenados en Firestore, seguí el tutorial y funcionó correctamente. Ahora estoy haciendo un proyecto escolar y necesito hacer lo mismo pero mostrando el RecyclerView en un fragment.

El problema está en FragmentPlace.kt al momento de usar el *this* como "context" cuando llamo al **Adapter** (adapter = AdapterSucursal(this)) y al **LinearLayoutManager** (recyclerViewId.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)); y también en el *this* cuando llamo **fetchSucursalData** (viewModel.fetchSucursalData().observe(this,...).

Mi código para PlaceFragment.kt

```
class PlaceFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var placeViewModel: PlaceViewModel

    private lateinit var adapter:AdapterSucursal
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(SucursalViewModel::class.java) }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        placeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PlaceViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place, container, false)
        
        return root


        adapter = AdapterSucursal(this)

        recyclerViewId.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerViewId.adapter = adapter
        observeData()
    }

    fun observeData(){
        viewModel.fetchSucursalData().observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.setListData(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
}
```

Agrego los demás archivos

AdapterSucursal.kt

```
class AdapterSucursal(private val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSucursal.SucursalViewHolder>() {

    private var dataList = mutableListOf<Sucursal>()

    fun setListData(data:MutableList<Sucursal>){
        dataList = data
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SucursalViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false)
        return SucursalViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        if (dataList.size > 0){
            return dataList.size
        } else{
            return 0
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SucursalViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val sucursal = dataList[position]
        holder.bindView(sucursal)
    }

    inner class SucursalViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        fun bindView(sucursal:Sucursal){
            Glide.with(context).load(sucursal.imagen1).into(itemView.imageView)
            itemView.nombreSucursal.text = sucursal.nombre
        }
    }
}
```

SucursalViewModel.kt

```
class SucursalViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val repo = Repo()

    fun fetchSucursalData(): LiveData<MutableList<Sucursal>>{
        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Sucursal>>()

        repo.getSucursalData().observeForever{ sucursalList ->
            mutableData.value = sucursalList
        }
        return mutableData
    }
}
```

Repo.kt

```
class Repo {

    fun getSucursalData():LiveData<MutableList<Sucursal>>{
        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Sucursal>>()

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Sucursales").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val listData = mutableListOf<Sucursal>()

            for (document in result){
                val nombre = document.getString("nombre")
                val domicilio = document.getString("domicilio")
                val telefono = document.getString("telefono")
                val horario = document.getString("horario")
                val imagen1 = document.getString("imagen1")
                val imagen2 = document.getString("imagen2")
                val imagen3 = document.getString("imagen3")
                val imagen4 = document.getString("imagen4")
                val latitud = document.getDouble("latitud")
                val longitud = document.getDouble("longitud")

                val sucursal = Sucursal(nombre!!, domicilio!!, telefono!!, horario!!, imagen1!!, imagen2!!, imagen3!!, imagen4!!, latitud!!, longitud!!)
                listData.add(sucursal)
            }
            mutableData.value = listData
        }
        return mutableData
    }
}
```

Sucursal.kt

```
data class Sucursal (val nombre:String = "DEFAULF NAME",
                     val domicilio:String = "DEFAULT DOMICILIO",
                     val telefono:String = "DEFAULT TELEFONO",
                     val horario:String = "DEFAULT HORARIO",
                     val imagen1:String = "DEFAULT IMAGE1",
                     val imagen2:String = "DEFAULT IMAGE2",
                     val imagen3:String = "DEFAULT IMAGE3",
                     val imagen4:String = "DEFAULT IMAGE4",
                     val latitud:Double = 0.0,
                     val longitud:Double = 0.0)
```

fragment_place.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.PlaceFragment.PlaceFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_row.kt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombreSucursal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TITULO"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar la imagen de la sucursal y el nombre, y más adelante programar para que al dar click abra otra activity donde se muestren todos los demás datos del lugar, pero por lo pronto quiero mostrar en el RecyclerView la imagen y el nombre de cada sucursal.

Gracias.

Comment: puedes usar "requireActivity()" en lugar de "this"

Comment: Hola, lo agregué y ya no me marca error, pero al iniciar la app no me muestra nada

Answer (score 1):

La clase Fragment no puede ser casteada a Context y estás retornando tu vista antes de inicializar tu adapter y recyclerView, prueba con este código:

```
class PlaceFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var placeViewModel: PlaceViewModel

    private lateinit var adapter:AdapterSucursal

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        placeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PlaceViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place, container, false)
        adapter = AdapterSucursal(requireContext())

        recyclerViewId.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requreContext())
        recyclerViewId.adapter = adapter
        observeData()
        return root
    }

    fun observeData(){
        viewModel.fetchSucursalData().observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.setListData(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
```